# hql Left Outer Join with join table

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

can I use left outer join with a join table?

i have player entity and member and member_player(join table),i want to store the result in a new object so i do that but i have a path exception join because no relationship between player and member_player

```
SELECT  new table (p.playerName_ar,p.playerName_fr,p.playerName_en, p.playerImage,preference_player.identifier) 
FROM Player as  p  
LEFT OUTER JOIN preference_player  ON  p.playerId = preference_player.playerId"
```

Comment: HQL doesn't work on tables. It works on entities, their properties and their associations. Whether an association is mapped using a join table or not doesn't change anything. Without knowing what your query should do, and what your entities look like, it's hard to help. Especially since the query you posted has nothing to do with the description before.

Comment: i find that i can not use left join if i have no relationship with the other entity so i chose to do that using hql native